# Easiest way to enter a JSON literal in Haskell ghci

Tags: json, haskell

I'm testing out some functions in ghci before I put them into a project, and I'm straining to find the simplest way to enter json literals in the ghci without a ton of boilerplate

For example, I'd like to try out:

```
myFuncThatTakesAJson
```

on inputs

```
x = {}
y = {"a": 1}
```

But when I try entering these:

```
import Text.JSON

Prelude> x = parseJSON "{}"
Prelude> y = parseJSON "{'a' : 1}"
```

I see errors like:

```
<interactive>:17:5: error:
    Variable not in scope: parseJSON :: [Char] -> t

y = fromJSON "{'a' : 1}"

<interactive>:20:5: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: FromJSON :: [Char] -> t
```

Is there any way to allow json objects to be entered as strings without defining full data types with custom FromJSON instances?

Comment: Aeson seems to have good interface which can discover json: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:3

Comment: As an aside, JSON doesn't allow single quotes. Use `"{\"a\": 1}"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There sure is! The type of a raw JSON value is [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value). With that in mind, here's a couple of ways of constructing a `Value` in GHCi:

- **with `parseJSON`**: since `Value` also has a `FromJSON` instance, you can use [`decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode) on it. Note that `aeson` is encouraging you to use `ByteString` instead of the inefficient default `String`. You can gloss over this detail by making string literals be overloaded by turning on `-XOverloadedStrings`:

  ```
  ghci> import Data.ByteString
  ghci> import Data.Aeson
  ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings
  ghci> x = decode "{}" :: Maybe Value
  x :: Maybe Value
  ghci> y = decode "{\"a\" : 1}" :: Maybe Value    -- note: single quotes won't work
  y :: Maybe Value
  ```
- **with quasiquotes**: you can also make use of the [`aesonQQ`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-QQ-Simple.html#v:aesonQQ) quasiquoter to get compile time JSON literals (this won't matter much in the REPL, beyond looking nicer, but in real code it means no actual parsing at runtime):

  ```
  ghci> import Data.Aeson.QQ.Simple
  ghci> :set -XQuasiQuotes
  ghci> x = [aesonQQ| {} |]
  x :: Value
  ghci> y = [aesonQQ| {"a" : 1} |]
  y :: Value
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  If I already have Text.JSON loaded, is there an easy way to hide its decode function so I can use the aeson one?  ```<interactive>:69:5: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘decode’
    It could refer to either ‘Data.Aeson.decode’,
                             imported from ‘Data.Aeson’
                          or ‘Text.JSON.decode’, imported from ‘Text.JSON’
```

Comment: @Mittenchops Just don't use `json`/`Text.JSON` at all. `aeson` is a much more polished library. :) otherwise, note you can always refer to something qualified (eg: `Data.Aeson.decode` instead of `decode`).

Comment: I know Stackoverflow closes questions that ask for software recommendations, but I appreciate this comment as a software recommendation.  This is a very helpful opinion.